# Set date in Vuetify date picker

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to set my Vuetify calender to a custom month and year in the past. But I don't want to set a date with the v-model.

So I went to the docs, and setting `picker-date="2020-02"` (Displayed year/month) should be a nice option.

So I tried:

```html
<v-date-picker v-model="picker" picker-date="2010-10"></v-date-picker>
```

But now I am not able to change the year / month from the picker

I can create something ugly like:

```html
<div id="app">
  <br><br>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  created() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.picker = ""
        }, 200);
  },
  data () {
    return {
      picker:'2020-06-04',
      //picker: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    }
  },
})
```

But its not so nice and solid

[Codepen over here](https://codepen.io/h3ll/pen/NWYyZdj?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new data for the picker date and bind it to the `v-date-picker`.

```html
<v-date-picker v-model="picker" :picker-date.sync="pickerDate"></v-date-picker>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    picker: '2020-06-04',
    pickerDate: '2020-10',
  }
},
```

Comment: Still I cant move the month now. Next and previous buttons are not working, I am not able to set the year / month after setting picker-date

Comment: Works fine for me. https://codepen.io/dEradicated/pen/NWYYpPY

Comment: Thanks I don't know why it was not working before, but it works now